# Extend Viewpage class with custom helper objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to add a custom helper object to the ViewPage class, so I can use it inside the view page markup (just like Html, Url and Ajax) ? This helper object also needs some data from a custom controller. (which should be possible through the ViewContext property I think)

Answer (score 5):

Create new class, derive it from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, add new property for custom helper and override InitHelpers() method. For example:

```
public class CustomViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{
    public YourCustomHelper CustomHelper
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual void InitHelpers()
    {
        CustomHelper = new YourCustomHelper(ViewContext);

        base.InitHelpers();
    }
}


public class YourCustomHelper
{
    public YourCustomHelper(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        if (viewContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
        }

        ViewContext = viewContext;
    }

    public ViewContext ViewContext
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks eugene, i also created a custom controller context and i access it like this: CustomHelper = new YourCustomHelper(ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext as CustomControllerContext);

Comment: +1! This is an excellent solution, too bad it's not marked as the answer and OP closed his account....

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, is there anything special that has to be done to use the `CustomViewPage` rather than the normal `ViewPage`

Comment: worked for me, +1... now looking for a way to extend the `ViewMasterPage`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with an extension method (now available in .Net 3.5)  Consider a class like this:

```
public static class ViewPageExtensions
{
    public static string DoSomething(this ViewPage page, string input)
    {
        // Do something clever with the page
    }
}
```

As long as your `ViewPageExtensions` class is visible to the namespaces you've imported on your ViewPage.aspx that you are working on, you should be able to access the `DoSomething` method directly, without referring to the ViewPageExtensions class.

Comment: I attempted this myself - nice in theory, but it appears this doesn't actually work in practice. The IDE does not recognize the extension methods. Oddly, from your view files, you can do stuff like <%=this.DoSomething("input")%> but not <%=DoSomething("input")%> which is not recognized by intellisense, and results in a runtime exception.

Comment: Shouldn't this work for `<%=Page.DoSomething("input")%>` as it's a `ViewPageExtension`?